# Xamarin.Forms: Add click event to map in <Grid>?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I was finally able to display the `ListView` using a `<Grid>` when clicking on a `button`. This is the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GasStations"
             x:Class="GasStations.MainPage">

    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MapGrid">
            <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200" 
                  x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="true"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Text="Show List" x:Name="Button_DisplayList"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" x:Name="listSection" IsVisible="false" HeightRequest="200">
            <ListView x:Name="ListView_Pets">
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>dog</x:String>
                        <x:String>cat</x:String>
                        <x:String>bird</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is the codebehind:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    listSection.IsVisible = true;
    Button_DisplayList.IsVisible = false;
}
```

When I click the button, the ListView is displayed and the button is hidden. So far so good.

Once the `ListView` is open, how can I hide the ListView again when I tap on the map?

I tried using `GestureRecognizers` and `<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>`, but it doesn't build.

Any help is appreciated.

I've included screenshots because I'm still learning the terminology.

[image]

Comment: try using the Focused event

Answer (score 1):

Adding gesture recognizer on the parent stacklayout of the map

On xaml:

```
 <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MapGrid">
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizer>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnMapAreaTapped"/>
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizer>
       <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="200" x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="true"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

On code behind:

```
private void OnMapAreaTapped(object sen, EventArgs e)
        {
           listSection.IsVisible = false;
           Button_DisplayList.IsVisible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using that, but I get error: `The attachable property 'GestureRecognizer' was not found in type 'StackLayout'`

Comment: I'm not encountering an error like that, adding `GestureRecognizer` on a `StackLayout` works well on mine. Is your Xamarin.Forms nuget updated ? @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf